# Hadoop says starting the datanode, starts it, but doesn't show up in jps later

Tags: hadoop

The datanode log:

ulimit -a for user sumitkhanna:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63202
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63202
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: �%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)
```

Essentially it gives errors in copying local files into hdfs.

Comment: Can you format your question better? Also, it's unclear what you are expecting for an answer. Have you checked the log files for the datanode? Does restarting services help?

Answer (score 0):

JPS output is inconsistent, depending on multiple factors that can usually be fixed, but I stopped trying. Use 'ps' as your source of truth:

```
ps ax | grep DataNode
```

Hopefully you'll see it then.

Answer (score 0):

this means that your datanode has not started yet. There was an exception while starting the dataNode. Please look at the datanode logs for the stacktrace.